# Is there a way to select a listbox (similar to clicking on it with mouse?)

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, listboxitem

I'm writing some VBA code for a user form. The values are selected in a listbox on the left (LB_Participants). Then "select" is pressed and the values are copied to a listbox on the right (LB_Output). I then want VBA to go through all these items seperatly in the LB_Output and look up other associated data from another worksheet. Problem I'm having is that somethimes the values are not selected. I check it with a messagebox and from time to time its blank. Then no associated data can be retrieved ofcourse. 
Before starting to fill in the userform, if I just click once on LB_Output (even without selecting any value) I don't have this problem. Many people will be using the userform so I don't want to explain tot them that they have to click first on the listbox before continuing... Is there something I'm not doing right? 
[Blank Msgbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j584s.png)

```
Dim ListCount As Integer
Dim z As Integer

ListCount = UserForm2.LB_Output.ListCount

For z = 0 To ListCount - 1
UserForm2.LB_Output.Selected(z) = True
TextString = UserForm2.LB_Output.Value
MsgBox (TextString)

'Split Participants into seperate names and copy them to data sheet
    WArray() = Split(TextString, ";")
    For Counter = LBound(WArray) To UBound(WArray)
        Dim LRNames As Integer
        If IsEmpty(Sheets("Data").Range("A1")) = True Then
        LRNames = 0
        Else
        LRNames = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
        Strg = WArray(Counter)
        Sheets("Data").Cells(LRNames + 1, 1) = Trim(Strg)
    Next Counter
Next z
```

Comment: Not on a machine, so can't look but... `SetFocus`?

Comment: Can you not use `.List` to capture the selected values?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but think you want to loop through all the items in LB_Output and process them regardless if selected or not - all the selection was done in the other listbox and those items moved to LB_Output.

This does not explicitly select each item, simply gets data from it.

```
For z = 0 to UserForm2.LB_Output.Listcount -1
   ' If you want to select the item to show 'progress' through the list,
   ' uncomment ...
   ' LB_Output.listindex = z
   ' The next line will still work as is
   TextString = UserForm2.LB_Output.List(z)
   '// Do processing with this item
Next
```